# How to convert spring bean integration From XML to Java annotation based Config

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I have this xml based configuration. But in my project I want to use java annotation based configuration. How to do the conversion?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="mail.csonth.gov.uk"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="registrationService" class="com.foo.SimpleRegistrationService">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you looking to use Annotation based configuration?

Comment: yes. like this, @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(); etc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a class annotated with `@Configuration` (`org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration`) and for each bean declaration in your XML file create a `@Bean` (`org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean`) method within this class.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("mail.csonth.gov.uk");
        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRegistrationService registrationService(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender, VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine) {
        SimpleRegistrationService registrationService = new SimpleRegistrationService();
        registrationService.setMailSender(mailSender);
        registrationService.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine); 
        return registrationService; 
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine() {
        VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
        Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
        velocityProperties.put("resource.loader", "class");
        velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        velocityEngine.setVelocityProperties(velocityProperties);
        return velocityEngine;
    }
}
```

This example assumes that the `mailSender` and `velocityEngine` beans are required elsewhere in your application config since this is implied by the XML config you supplied. If this is not the case i.e. if the `mailSender` and `velocityEngine` beans are **only** required to construct the `registrationService` bean then you do not need to declare the `mailSender()` and `velocityEngine()` methods as public nor do you need to annotate then with `@Bean`.

You can instruct Spring to read this configuration class by

- Component scanning e.g. `@ComponentScan("your.package.name")`
- Registering the class with an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` e.g.

  ```
     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
     context.register(MyConfiguration.class);
     context.refresh();
  ```

Comment: And yes, For all other user defined classes, you can use @Autowired to inject the bean into the spring container

Comment: What do I need to import? like this org.springframework.context.annotation

Comment: add Spring 3.0 jar or above version

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe: I have updated the answer to (a) include fully qualified package names for the Configuration and Bean annotations and (b) explain how to register a configuration class with your ApplicationContext.

Comment: on both those method I get missing return statement error

Comment: @Sandu_prass I have updated the answer to add the return statements.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @glitch was helpful but I got an error at below line.

```
velocityEngine.setVelocityProperties("resource.loader=class", "class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
```

How ever I fixed that. Find below is the full implementation

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import com.vlclabs.adsops.service.SendEmailServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("mail.csonth.gov.uk");
        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SendEmailServiceImpl registrationService(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender, VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine) {
        SendEmailServiceImpl registrationService = new SendEmailServiceImpl();
        registrationService.setMailSender(mailSender);
        registrationService.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine.getObject()); 
        return registrationService;
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine() {

        VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
        Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
        velocityProperties.put("resource.loader", "class");
        velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        velocityEngine.setVelocityProperties(velocityProperties);

        return velocityEngine;
    }
}
```